# How to avoid potential noise after Canny?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, video-processing

I have a time averaged grayscale frame of a video:
[image: Time averaged frame]

I applied Canny edge detector to that frame, but sometimes there is noise like this:
[image: frame after Canny]

I want to extract the area of a TV logo using `boundingRect()`, but it works wrong if there is noise.
How can I avoid it?

Comment: Is the logo going to be the same all the time? Or are you talking about creating a general logo detection module?

Comment: You could do some gaussian smoothing before you apply Canny, but I am not sure if this will work in all cases. I would not call this noise either, there are clearly more edges than the logo.

Comment: Rather than taking the average over all frames, find pixels that don't change across the frames.

Comment: @Ananda yes, tv logo is the same all the time. I just want to identify the TV logo region and afterward track when it disappears (about 10% of all frames)

Comment: @Cris not exactly every pixel of a logo is the same through all frames. Some frames they can be different